# Ant and XML configuration file parsing

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have an XML file of the following form -

```
<map MAP_XML_VERSION="1.0">
    <entry key="database.user" value="user1"/>
    ...
</map>
```

Does ant have a native ability to read this and let me perform an xquery to pull back values for keys? Going through the API I did not see such capabilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) tag to create a JavaScript wrapper for your class.  Inside JS, you pretty much have the full power of Java and can do any kind of complicated XML parsing you want.

For example:

```
<project default="build">        
    <target name="build">            
        <xpath-query query="//entry[@key='database.user']/@value"
                     xmlFile="test.xml" addproperty="value"/>
        <echo message="Value is ${value}"/>    
    </target>

    <scriptdef name="xpath-query" language="javascript">
        <attribute name="query"/>
        <attribute name="xmlfile"/>
        <attribute name="addproperty"/>

        <![CDATA[
            importClass(java.io.FileInputStream);
            importClass(javax.xml.xpath.XPath);
            importClass(javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants);
            importClass(javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory);
            importClass(org.xml.sax.InputSource);

            var exp = attributes.get("query");
            var filename = attributes.get("xmlfile");
            var input = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(filename));
            var xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            var value = xpath.evaluate(exp, input, XPathConstants.STRING);

            self.project.setProperty( attributes.get("addproperty"), value );

        ]]>

    </scriptdef>
</project>
```

Comment: So far I definitely like this approach but I am running into an issue. At the evaluate call it hangs for 30-40 seconds, and I get a javax.script.ScriptException wrapping a javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException. I get this even when I simplify the query to select the entire document. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd have to see the XML you're working with and the xpath query.  The sample above is only designed to select text elements.  Its possible that you're trying to select a node or node set.

Comment: It should be returning the value of the attribute "value" of the element "entry". The xpath query is identical to what you put into the example there. The only thing I neglected to mention was there is a doctype (<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/preferences.dtd">) and the standard xml header at the top.

Comment: I bet it's trying to resolve the preferences.dtd across the wire.

Comment: Kudos to you Brian, that's exactly what the problem was. Question resolved.

Comment: One more question - I've been struggling with trying to create an extension of org.xml.sax.EntityResolver, and I can't figure out the syntax to do so. I need to put in : class MyEntityResolver implements EntityResolver{ public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId){ return new InputSource(new StringReader("")); }}
But it complains about "class". Are you allowed to create classes like this in a scriptdef, or do I have to move this out to a java file?

Comment: I just found "http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html" which should cover what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

The optional Ant task [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) is designed to do this. Give it an XPath expression and you can select the above into (say) a property. [Here's an article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html) on how to use it, with examples. It'll do tons of other XML-related manipulations/querying/creation as well.

e.g.

```
<xmltask source="map.xml">
   <!-- copies to a property 'user' -->
   <copy path="/map/entry[@key='database.user']/@value" attrValue="true" property="user"/>
</xmltask>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like [ant-xpath-task](http://code.google.com/p/ant-xpath-task/). I'm not aware of a built-in way to do this with Ant.