# Run test from eclipse feature using ANT

Tags: java, ant, scripting

I have a feature with test plugins. And i use ant+jococo for run test-suite from each plugin. Test-suites have the same name like "Tests". Now use hardcoded plugin names like 
`<run-test-macro test='plugin.name.Test'/>` (hardcoded values in target).

**How can i do this without using hardcoded plugin names**, i want to get those plugin-names from the feature-XML in ANT and foreach plugin call my macro.

I found approach but i don't think that this is the good idea:
I could use XPath like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256238/ant-and-xml-configuration-file-parsing) and ant loop which will change regexp in xpath to skip already runned tests.

Comment: EDIT for bounty: Needed solution without using XPATH and automatically picking up JUnit test fragments

Comment: Or if you clearly describe that this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things here which are not straight forward in Ant: extract some info from some xml, and a loop.

To extract some xml:

- there is the javascript solution you [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256238/ant-and-xml-configuration-file-parsing)
- there are some external xpath task available. I used [andariel](http://andariel.uworks.net/) and it worked fine for my use case. If you google 'xpath ant task' you may find other implementation.
- use some regexp with the [loadfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) Ant task and the filterchain [replaceregex](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex). To be used only if your not afraid of regexp and be ok to be sensible to the actual xml syntax (additional line break, spaces...)

To loop, and deal with condition (from what I understand from 'ant loop which will change regexp in xpath to skip already runned tests'): only one decent solution, use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html). Look for the `for`, `foreach` and `if` tasks.

Comment: It's a pitty that there isn't any "in box solution" for running feature plugin tests. Cos' ant compile all plugin that placed in the feature i thought that there should be a possibility to divide this process on compile part of every plugin and doing something with plugin...