# how to update multiple components in XML using ant

Tags: xml, ant

I want to update the numericals values in Regist and Manage components in below xml file using ant

XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<Application>  
<component>  
<name>Regist</name>  
<filename>v1.5.0.4-Regist.zip</filename>  
<version>v1.5.0.4</version>  
<size>1001518</size>  
</component>  
<component>
<name>Manage</name>  
<filename>v1.5.1.1-manage.jar</filename>  
<version>v1.5.1.1</version>  
<size>3795024</size>  
</component>  
</Application>
```

Ant is able to traverse the script but unable to differentiate the components due to above structure. It identify the above xml components as below properties,

```
Application.component.filename=v1.5.0.4-Regist.zip,v1.5.1.1-manage.jar   
Application.component.name=Regist,Manage   
Application.component.size=1001518,3795024   
Application.component.version=v1.5.0.4,v1.5.1.1
```

We are running components Regist and Manage separately and the new values will be updated to this XML with respect to component

Is there any way to pull the properties with respect to component through ant ?

Comment: Use xmltask => http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask combined with relevant XPath  expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to use XPath to uniquely identify each component. First, [there is a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256238/ant-and-xml-configuration-file-parsing). I guess you did not know to [search for Xpath, because that's what will help you in this situation](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). Still, I'll summarize a few options in this answer.

### [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/)

Looks like the best option. To pull a XML value into a property:

```
<xmltask source="map.xml">
  <!-- copies to a property 'user' -->
  <copy path="/map/entry[@key='database.user']/@value" attrValue="true" property="user"/>
</xmltask>
```

### [ant-xpath-task](https://code.google.com/p/ant-xpath-task/wiki/Introduction)

It also looks like it can pull values out of XML into system properties, but the documentation is sorely lacking:

```
<target name="find-hrefs">
  <xpath document="foo.xhtml" xpath="/html/body/a/@href" outputproperty="hrefs"/> 
</target>
```

### [Script Engine via Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html)

This is mentioned in the related SO question. It uses Javascript in the answer to extract data out of the XML and store it in system properties. Nowadays though, maybe you can use  Groovy or Scala script engine support for a more succinct syntax.

### [Core style ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)

Use a [XSLT to perform manipulation on XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/). That won't help you pull values out of the XML I think, but you might need to change some values or nodes.

Comment: @user2935276 Hope it works for you! I added more links to the answer now that I have more than 10 of reputation.

Comment: Glad to hear that! GJ!